# Render a markdown table with React

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I'm using React and need to render server response that looks like this:

```
        '| --------------------- | ---------- | ------------- |\n' +
        '| text                  | String     | Empty String  |\n' +
        '| buttonBackgroundColor | Int        | Default Color |\n' +
        '| action                | () -> Unit | Empty         |';
```

Using React markdown but it doesn't do anything:

```
<ReactMarkdown className={styles.markdown} source={example} />
```

Tried adding RemarkGFM to it, didn't make any difference either:

```
<ReactMarkdown className={styles.markdown} remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]} source={example} />
```

Do you know where I'm wrong? Thank you for your advice in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `source` is the right prop?

Comment: Yep, `source` works on its own, and I can render the list of items no problem. It's only the table that doesn't work. That makes me think that I might need to check if table markdown input is correct.

Comment: Yes you have to check if the value is as expected. Also, I've never used `ReactMarkdown` but you should try pass it a hardcoded data for the `source` value, and see if that works as expected, so you'll know where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

I've realized what was causing the issue. I have been using an outdated version of `react-markdown` library (5.0.3). Upgrade to the latest one (8.0.7) has fixed the issue, and everything started to work as expected. I'd to update the syntax as well to fit the current version.